# Save keystroke then use with SendKeys

Tags: c#

I have a form button that I can focus on and then press a key on my keyboard to save the keycode to a variable.

```
private void Button_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var key = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    }
```

If I press "1" on my keyboard the variable will say "D1".

My goal is to re-use this variable with `SendKeys.SendWait();`, but I have no idea how to get this to work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try storing that variable in the instance and not within a method:

```
private string savedKey = "";

private void Button_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    savedKey = ((char)e.KeyValue).ToString();
}
```

This will store the value of the key you pressed.

And then `SendKeys.SendWait(savedKey)` (or `Send`) will simulate a keypress on your keyboard so simply the currently focused element will receive it.

How you should implement this depends on where you would like to put the saved key.

Comment: Nice, this works on normal keys. Next problem is doing the same with special characters. One example is pipe: " | " This ends up being "Oem5". This does not work with SendKeys.

Comment: For that you should use the KeyPress event instead of the KeyDown event. There you'll have the KeyPressEventArgs which has the KeyChar property (instead of the KeyValue).